# Why is my test unable to locate the radio button?

Tags: ruby, element

While running a test script to select a radio button, the following error appears and the test is halted:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in
`assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:name
=>"r(g544i56094)", :value=>"17617", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"radio"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException) from
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:118:in
`click' from code-test5.rb:709:in `<main>'
```

The code I have been using and which worked on all other test cases in the script is as follows:

```
if browser.radio(:name => "r(g545i56094)", :value => "#{pmg}").exists?
```

Ruby does not recognize the element name `r(g545i56094)`. I double checked the element name and it is correct. On all previous test cases which use this code with various element names, the element name is recognized and the test scripts run normally.

Why does Ruby choke on this particular element name?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had ruby choke on an element name.
If the element is within an iframe you must first identify the frame, and then the object within the frame.

I also had issues where there was a trailing whitespace at the end of names or ids when identifying objects, and had to use partial strings to identify them, like so.

```
if browser.radio(:name => /r(g545i56094)/, :value => "#{pmg}").exists?
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, however I tried the code "if browser.radio(:name => /r(g545i56094)/, :value => "#{pmg}").exists?"; still Ruby did not locate the element named r(g545i56094)resulting in the same error appearing.

Comment: @dcwilson042 have you checked to see if the radio button is within a frame like:`browser.frame(:how => 'what').radio(:name => /r(g545i56094)/, :value => "#{pmg}").exists? ` If an object is located within a frame, you _must_ include the frame in the target path, it needs to know the context of where the element is on the page